# ECONNRESET/ETIMEDOUT error with mysql2 nodejs pooled connection

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a node/express/mysql2 web app that accesses a mySql DB through a connection pool object and I often run into the following issue: I leave the code for a while then when i come back and access pages that run queries I'll get

> Error in foo: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
>
> Error in bar: Error: read ECONNRESET

I guess that on the other side mysql sees idle connections and close them, the client app doesn't know that, get those connections from the pool and then run into those issues, fine. But I was under the impression that this was automatically handled by mysql2 ?

This is roughly how i organised the db code

***sqlConnectionPool.js***

```js
const dbParam = require('./dbParam.js');
const sqlPool = require('mysql2/promise').createPool(dbParam.connection.prod);

module.exports = sqlPool;
```

***dummyQuery.js***

```js
const sqlPool = require('./sqlConnectionPool.js');
module.exports.updatefoo = async (ID, sqlConnection = undefined) => {
  let connection;
  try {
    connection = sqlConnection === undefined ? await sqlPool.getConnection() : await sqlConnection;
    const [updateResult] = await connection.query('update foo set barID=?', [ID]);
    if (updateResult.affectedRows !== 1) {
      throw (new Error(`error on ID ${ID}`));
    }
    return undefined;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error in updatefoo: ${err}`);
    return err;
  } finally {
    if (sqlConnection === undefined) {
      connection.release();
    }
  }
};
```

Is there something I'm missing to have those errors automatically handled, or simply not run into them ? I guess the mysql2 library needs to close the connection when they get connreset or conntimeout error and return them to the pool...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like `setTimeout()` to jab good the DB.